# Dispatcher.BeginInvoke , trying to use lambda to get string set from textblock, but getting conversion error

Tags: c#, wpf, delegates, lambda

I am trying to call a selected listbox item from a button, not the `listbox.selecteditemchanged` method in wpf.  So when i try

```
string yadda = listbox.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

i get an exception:

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

So, what i was trying to do is the following:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                    {
                        lbxSelectedItem =  (lbxFileList.SelectedItem as TextBlock).Text;
                    });
```

That is not working either because i get another exception:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: BeginInvoke requires an argument of type Delegate, not enough type info to convince the C# compiler to accept a lamda.  Other than casting to Action or MethodInvoker, an anonymous method still works best.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Convert the lambda to an `Action`:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { /*DoStuff*/ }));
```

Or construct one from the lambda:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { /*DoStuff*/ }));
```

---

You probably can write an extension method for the `Dispatcher` that takes an `Action`, that way the lambda would be implicitly converted.